# In which directory should you install python modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, directory

As the question asks, which directory should you install python modules? I am installing mine into the `C:\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39` directory. The issue I am having is that the specific module I am trying to install isn't being recognized by python. Should I rather use the `C:\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib` directory? I'm lost, any help would be vastly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

usually, the Lib contains all the libraries in your local machine but I'll suggest an alternative, Try installing anaconda in your local machine. You can maintain your own environment and your libraries in an organized manner.
Look into [Documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you installing the modules manually use pip to install modules , they will be automatically saved to lib directory

Comment: I am using pip, I am not sure which directory I should use.

Comment: If you are using pip then by default all the modules should be installed in the lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I wasn't using the right syntax for the pip installation.
I should have used `pip3 install [module]`, but I had used `pip install [module]`.
Fixed!

Comment: Then your issue was that you were not using the correct Python interpreter. -- You should never call the `pip`, `pip3`, `pipX.Y` scripts directly. Instead you should always prefer the surefire way of calling the executable _pip_ module for a specific Python interpreter: `python -m pip`, `python3 -m pip`, `pythonX.Y -m pip`, `path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip`, etc. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/